# How to substract 1 from grep result

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash command that sums the number of services running on specified ports. In my case 4092, 4903, 4904, 4905. Below is my command:

```
ps -ef | grep '4905\|4904\|4903\|4902' | wc -l
```

OUTPUT: 5

Here "\|" serves as OR operator. Now the result of this is 5, since it greps the command itself. How can I subtract 1 from the answer so that the output is 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save the `wc` and use `awk` to get the expected number

```
ps -ef|grep ...|awk 'END{print NR-1}'
```

Comment: @JID thx it was a typo, fixed, yep, he had `\|` in pattern, ok, remove the 2nd part.

Comment: @JID yep, but it is too much typing in this case, so I won't suggest it. :-)

Comment: Thanks kent. While others answers are also correct, I have used this one.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
ps -ef  | grep '4905\|4904\|4903\|4902' | wc -l | awk '{print $0-1}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the last line that contains the result itself before you print number of matches:

```
ps -ef  | grep '4905\|4904\|4903\|4902' | head -n -1 | wc -l
```